# How to import a file from another folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have the following folder structure:

```
...
 │
 ├── src
 │    ├── folder_A
 │    │    └── file_A.py
 │    │    └── __init__.py
 │    │       
 │    ├── folder_B
 │    │    └── file_B.py
 │    │    └── __init__.py
 │    │
 │    └── __init__.py
 │
 │
 └── something else
```

In the file `file_A.py` I put `from folder_B import file_B as fb`. But `file_A.py` works only in debug mode (meaning that the code produces the expected results). If I run `file_A.py` in the standard way I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_B'`.

I also changed the configuration before running the code, putting `C:\Users\***\***\***\src` as the working directory of `file_A.py` but it still doesn't work.

What can be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your current directory is `src`, then `folder_B` is in the path because of that. If you want to make a package with sub-packages that can access each other, place everything into a root package:

```
 │
 ├── src
 │    └── root_package
 │         ├── folder_A
 │         │    ├── file_A.py
 │         │    └── __init__.py
 │         │       
 │         ├── folder_B
 │         │    ├── file_B.py
 │         │    └── __init__.py
 │         │
 │         └── __init__.py
 │
 └── something else
```

Now in `file_A`, you can do

```
from ..folder_B import file_B as fb
```

Since `src` is not a package, you can't do a relative import through it. By adding `root_package`, you make it possible to find `folder_B` in the same package hierarchy (albeit a different branch) as the module doing the import.

Comment: I don't understand the need to introduce the folder `folder_root`. Isn't there a way to leave the folder structure untouched?

Comment: @LJG. I made a typo (now fixed), and added an explanation.

Comment: There was a file `__init__.py` in `src` as well, my mistake. I have corrected my question. But I don't know if that changes the answer. I wish I could fix it without changing the folder structure.

Comment: @LJG. It's standard to add one more folder just so your package name isn't `src`. The point still holds: you can go the same relative import in your case as I did here

Comment: @LJG. I also put `__init__` into `src` unintentionally. Fixed now

Comment: Since the project is not mine and I'm not working on it myself, I don't know if I can change the structure of the subfolders. So you confirm that the only way is to add the folder `root_package`? It is not important that the package is called `src`.

Comment: @LJG. If `src` already has an `__init__.py` you can use the relative import shown above. It does not matter what the folder is called, as long as it has an `__init__.py` and contains the two folders trying to reach each other.